# Timestamp operations in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, impala

How can I subtract 2 timestamp columns in hive and store the result in a separate column in its equivalent hours format?

Comment: I basically have  2 columns: **start_date** and **end_date** in a table in hive and I want to populate a new column called **elapsed_hours** by running a DML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say if you have timestamp in the given format : **2016-10-16 10:51:00.000**

You can try following:

```
SELECT
  cast(
    round(
      cast((e-s) as double) * 1000
    ) as int
  ) time_difference
FROM (SELECT cast(starttime as double) s, cast(endtime as double) e from table1) q;
```

It will give you the difference of both timestamps in millisecond. Then you can convert it to your expected format(hours,days etc.) .

Comment: It gives me an error saying **Missing Keyword** after cast function

Comment: Hope you renamed the columns as per schema. Can you please tell the entire error you are getting?

Comment: What about doing the opposite? <br/> Adding a column populated with hours to a timestamp column and getting the output in another timestamp column?

Answer (score 0):

Use the unix_timestamp function to convert a hive timestamp to a number of seconds since epoch.  Subtracting the unix timestemp results gives an answer in seconds.

```
    SELECT start_dttm,
             (unix_timestamp(end_dttm) - unix_timestamp(start_dttm))/60 AS duration_in_minutes
    FROM dev_edw.audit_history_hb
    WHERE script_name LIKE '%0_hive_d%'
            AND parent_audit_id is null
    ORDER BY start_dttm desc
```